# Assembly in Visual Studio 2012 - Red syntax error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I've just created a platform for ASM using Irvine Tutorial at http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2012/index.htm

Everything works just fine, In order to create a new project I just open an existing project of Irvine Examples and add my own assembly file (otherwise in case I create my own project I get error regarding missing EXE file).

The more complicated issue is the syntax of the Visual Studio. I'm getting a red underline under comments as you can see in the attached image.

These errors don't prevent compiling or running of the ASM program but it is really annoying to view tbe code or writing the code with these strong red syntax errors in front of the eyes.

Do you know this issue? How can I fix it? Why does it happen? Is it realted to the intellisense?

See attached image :

[image]
Thank you